# How can I prevent programmers from capturing data entered by users?

Tags: security

I'm developing a web application with a strong focus on security. What measures can be taken to prevent those who work on the application (programmers, DBAs, quality assurance staff) from capturing user entered values that should be well-protected, such as passwords, social security numbers, and so forth?

Comment: I would suggest that you post the question in: http://security.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: "Prevent" is a very strong word.  You can't *prevent* bad actors from doing bad things.  What you *can* do is learn and apply fundamental security principles like "least privilege," "separation of duties" and "implicit deny," architect things in secure ways, and hire people that you can trust.  Have workable plans in place to mitigate the damage when the inevitable eventually occurs.

Comment: The technical terms for the technologies that you need: *hashing and encryption.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is quite simple.  Banks do it all the time.

You have three groups of people involved.  These are security groups.  With distinct authorizations.

Developers cannot assign security authorizations and cannot see production data.

Operators cannot assign security authorizations and cannot create software.

Security folks who set the authorizations and can neither create software nor operate the software.

The developers create software.  The operators install it and operate it.  The security folks assure that the two groups are kept separated.

Comment: So is the security person responsible for database security not capable of running a SELECT statement?

Comment: OK, but a developer could still add something into the system that emails production data to his/her private account; or writes production data to some server where he/she will pick it up.  I think the only way around this is with a rigorous code-review regime.

Comment: There is always that level of trust that is given to employees. Someone has to have the keys to the palace, and if you can't trust that they understand the power that is given to them, then maybe we shouldn't be giving those keys to that person in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but having keys that require more than one person (like code review regime) means that you need two to go "astray" before you are compromised and that is less likely than "just one" employee going astray and abusing the key given to them. It's all a matter of balancing trust and the consequences of that trust being abused. And don't forget that people and circumstances change. A person trustwhorthy when the keys are given can have things happen in life by which (s)he becomes less trustworthy...

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Correct.  Security person sets and resets groups and passwords, but can't see data.  Only operators can see real data.  Think of data like actual money handled by actual tellers.  Programmers don't touch the money; only tellers to.  Similarly, security people don't touch money; only tellers touch money.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was just wondering how would one go abut setting such permissions in a DBMS...I will need to study on that.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: DBA's are not developers. There are two groups: security and data.  Data DBA's are a special part of "operations".  They should **not** have authorization to change security; they cannot write code; they will see data, however, and must be treated like operators, not developers.

Answer (score 2):

The programmers don't have access to the production servers. But someone has to have access. There's no way around it. And there's always a chance that someone may go insane and abuse their access.

Data that is hashed/salted is theoretically secure even from the people who have full access to view it. But most data is not appropriate for hashing.